# Generator Function Vs Loops

Tags: javascript, generator

I am reading about "yield" keyword usage in Generator Function. What still not obvious for me is why to use generator functions?

For example, if I have a "generate_number" function then I can generate a sequence of numbers by calling it in a loop instead of in a generator function and then use next().

In other words, what is the advantages of using  generator function rather than a loop?

Comment: In what programming language?

Comment: Of course I replied. It's an internet connection i think. However, It is JavaScript.

Comment: Generator functions aren't used as alternatives to the existing functionalities. They are there to introduce new abstracts to simplify more complicated tasks. One example to that might be coding asynchronous workflow inside the generator function with an approach as if they are synchronous. I would recommend a good read on that https://curiosity-driven.org/promises-and-generators